# responsive sidebar that is also fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I have a responsive design where my sidebar is 25% and my content is 75%. My problem is when I scroll the page the sidebar is not fixed and doesn't scroll down with the page.

I tried making it position:fixed but then I loose the whole percentage responsiveness with the content.

How can I achieve both of this?

**fiddle:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXMmOz

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container max-width">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.max-width {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin-top: 54px;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 25%;
  padding-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;  
}

.content {
  background-color: black;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    left: -200px;
    position: fixed;
  }
  .content {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are positioning the sidebar as absolute.  That will ignore the parent element and use the body as the reference.  You should use position: relative.

You should also float the content right, instead of using margin left 25%..

I'll work up a fiddle for you.  I've never used codepen before.

OK, have a look at this.  Is this close to what your looking for ?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJZYvB

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.max-width {
  max-width: 1300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;

  left: 0px;




}

.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 25%;
  padding-top: 0;

  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
  height: 100%;

}

.content {
  background-color: black;
  width: 75%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    left: -200px;
    position: fixed;
  }
  .content {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Looking forward to see your approach!

Comment: updated my answer, have a look and  let me know if it's better or worse. haha :)

Comment: Thanks I just took a look at it, but I can't get the two columns centered, I tried margin: 0 auto but it's not working.

Comment: So you want the left sidebar to not be along the left ?